# Issue on nested arithmetics MySQL queries on webserver

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery

I made a little webapp maded with PHP+HTML5+JS, the app work flawless on my local webserver (on my laptop), I'm using XAMPP v3.2.2 with Server version: 10.1.9-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution.

I uploaded all files and imported the database to a webserver, and I get an weird error in one PHP file that exec a MySQL query to the database.

I got the query and manually exec on my local phpMyAdmin and works with no errors, but in the webserver there is a syntax error :(

This is an example of the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 100 AS cyear, DATE_FORMAT( personas.fecha, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS fecha, 1 AS numb, personas
.id_persona, personas.distancia, (
    personas.rating - (
        SELECT valor.valor FROM valor WHERE valor.valor=1 AND valor.distancia=(
            SELECT personas.distancia WHERE personas.id_persona=1))) AS calc, (personas.rating +
 personas.rating - (
                SELECT valor.valor FROM valor WHERE valor.valor=1 AND valor.distancia=(
                    SELECT personas.distancia WHERE personas.id_persona=1))) As clase, personas.rating
FROM personas, valor WHERE personas.id_persona=1 AND valor.valor=1
```

**The Error:** #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

What's is wrong? I have hours trying to find out, maybe I use some deprecated functions? Thanks for reading and please forgive that bad english.

Comment: The webserver on internet use `MySQL` instead `MariaDB`. This version: Server version: 5.6.33 MySQL Community Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `FROM personas` in two places.

For some reason MariaDB doesn't mind it but MySQL sees it as a syntax error.

Here's the fixed code: (No syntax errors.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 100 AS cyear, DATE_FORMAT( personas.fecha, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS fecha, 1 AS numb, personas
.id_persona, personas.distancia, (
    personas.rating - (
        SELECT valor.valor FROM valor WHERE valor.valor=1 AND valor.distancia=(
            SELECT personas.distancia FROM personas WHERE personas.id_persona=1))) AS calc, (personas.rating +
 personas.rating - (
                SELECT valor.valor FROM valor WHERE valor.valor=1 AND valor.distancia=(
                    SELECT personas.distancia FROM personas WHERE personas.id_persona=1))) As clase, personas.rating
FROM personas, valor WHERE personas.id_persona=1 AND valor.valor=1
```